# Error handling for a simple 'fetch some data, then save the data' Node function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, asynchronous

This is a fairly simple bit of code:

```
async function fetchData() {
    console.log("fetching data");
    let json;
    try {
        const data = await fetch(endPoint);
        json = await data.json();    
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        handleError(error);
    }

    try {
        await saveData(json);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        handleError(error);
    }
}

console.info("start running");
setInterval(fetchData, config.newsapi.polling_interval);
console.info("application is running");
```

What we're doing is - every 15 minutes or so, we're polling an API endpoint, and then saving the results into a database.

So there's two main kinds of errors we might get here:

- The API I fetched the data from might return some kind of error - it might be down, or my API key might be wrong, or I've gone over the rate limit or whatever.
- The database might return some kind of error. For all the same reasons, but a completely different service.

Now in terms of handling these errors, for now all I'll be doing is logging the error, and send me an email.

But I can imagine, that in the future, I might want to handle these two distinct kinds of errors differently. As such, I've created two different `try` `catch` blocks, that gives me the flexibility to handle them differently.

But it does look a bit messier, in my opinion. The other way I could write this is:

```
async function fetchData() {
    console.log("fetching data");
    try {
        const data = await fetch(endPoint);
        const json = await data.json(); 
        await saveData(json);   
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        handleError(error);
    }

}

console.info("start running");
setInterval(fetchData, config.newsapi.polling_interval);
console.info("application is running");
```

This looks so much tidier. But in which case - it seems like the error handling is a bit trickier.

I guess I could put a `switch` statement in the catch block handle different errors differently, but is that a bit messy? Any suggestions or guidelines for navigating this?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is much better to place the `saveData` call inside the first try-catch block.

This avoids calling `saveData` with an undefined value in case an exception occurs in calls to `fetch` or `data.json`, and gives the `json` variable a clean scope.

Depending on the granularity needed for error handling I would prefer to surround

```
await saveData(json);
```

with try-catch if necessary. However, a switch statement could also be a natural approach if you have a clear distinction on the exceptions thrown (e.g. error numbers).

Answer (score 1):

## `Promise.catch` for errors

Why use an `async function` at all?

You are using an interval that ignores the promise returned by the `async fetchData`, so you are not interested in whether or not the get and post succeed, you just want to report errors as they happen.

Promises have a `catch` callback that is called when there is an error. Simply redirect the error passed to the `catch` to your `handleError` function.

That way you can handle the errors in the functions who's role is appropriate rather than have `fetchData` handle both the get or post errors

```
function postData(data) {
   const url = ????;
   const options = {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(data), 
       headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
   };
   fetch(url, options).catch(handleError);
}

function getData() {
    fetch(endPoint)
        .then(data => { data.json().then(postData) }) //assumes JSON is reliably formated 
        .catch(handleError);      
}

setInterval(getData, config.newsapi.polling_interval);
```